# In Python with selenium, what does the Unused variable 'x'pylint(unused-variable) mean?

Tags: python, selenium

I am making a bot for a web app videogame but I get this error ('Unused variable 'x'pylint(unused-variable)) and I don't really understand it as to why I am getting it.

```
def redeem_pack_coins():
        for x in range(0, 5):
            try:
                bronzePackRedeem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]')
                bronzePackRedeem.click()
                break
            except:
                time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the variable `x`. In your long, your are essentially assigning each value in range(0,5) to x, but you never use `x`.

You could try something like this if you just want to run it 5 times:

```
import itertools

for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 5):
    ...
```